# Code a SQL statement to change the type to "geeky" for any book that has the word "Computer" or "Networking" in the title

Tags: sql

Code a SQL statement to change the type to "geeky" for any book that has the word "Computer" or "Networking" in the title

```
UPDATE book
      SET type = 'geeky'
WHERE title = %Computer% or %Networking%
```

The code isn't right. What can I use in the WHERE clause to choose these two words and type them as geeky?

Comment: Look up the LIKE clause.  You are close..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
UPDATE book
SET type = 'geeky'
WHERE title like '%Computer%' 
or 
title like '%Networking%'
```